# Button unable to click when Thread.Sleep

Tags: c#, delay

I understand that when Thread.Sleep is being executed, the buttons on my GUI are not able to be clicked on.

Is there any other ways to delay my codes from flowing yet still able to click on my buttons on the GUI?

For example right now after my codes execute Thread.Sleep(10000); and within this 10 seconds i'm not able to click on my button1 event, is there anyway that I can still click on my button1 event within these 10 seconds?

```
        private void displaydata_event2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txt_data.AppendText(in_data + "\n");
        string inStr;
        inStr = in_data;

        //MessageBox.Show(inStr.Length.ToString());

        if (inStr.Length == 12)
        {
            int indexOfSpace = inStr.IndexOf(' ');
            string Patient = inStr.Substring(indexOfSpace + 1);

            int rx = 0;
            int selected = 0;

            txtData1.Text = Patient;

            rx = Convert.ToInt16(Patient);
            selected = Convert.ToInt16(txt_pnorec.Text);

            if (rx != selected)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please check patient settings");
            }
        }
        else if (inStr.Length == 24)
        {
            label2.Text = "Patient is not selected!";
            label2.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else if (inStr.Length == 10)
        {
            int indexOfSpace = inStr.IndexOf(':');
            string Temp = inStr.Substring(indexOfSpace + 1);

            txtData2.Text = Temp;

            double tempflo;
            tempflo = Convert.ToDouble(Temp);

            if (tempflo > 20)
            {
                lbl_temp.Text = "Fever";
                lbl_temp.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
        else if (inStr.Length == 9)
        {
            int indexOfSpace = inStr.IndexOf(':');
            string ECG = inStr.Substring(indexOfSpace + 1);

            txtData3.Text = ECG;
        }
        else if (inStr.Length == 19 || inStr.Length == 20)
        {
            int indexOfSpace = inStr.IndexOf(':');
            string Systolic = inStr.Substring(indexOfSpace + 1);

            txtData4.Text = Systolic;
        }
        else if (inStr.Length == 21 || inStr.Length == 22)
        {
            int indexOfSpace = inStr.IndexOf(':');
            string Diastolic = inStr.Substring(indexOfSpace + 1);

            txtData5.Text = Diastolic;
        }
        else if (inStr.Length == 16)
        {
            int indexOfSpace = inStr.IndexOf(':');
            string Pulse = inStr.Substring(indexOfSpace + 1);

            txtData6.Text = Pulse;
        }

        else if (inStr.Length == 23 || inStr.Length == 17 || inStr.Length == 27 || inStr.Length == 30 || inStr.Length == 35 || inStr.Length == 29)
        {
            lbl_bp.Text = inStr;//to display status of BP (Normal,prehypotension etc)

            string bp;

            bp = inStr;

            if (bp.Length == 23 || bp.Length == 27 || bp.Length == 31 || bp.Length == 35 || bp.Length == 30)
            {
                lbl_bp.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else if (bp.Length == 17)
            {
                lbl_bp.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
            }
        }

        else if (inStr.Length == 32 || inStr.Length == 25 || inStr.Length == 34 || inStr.Length == 33 || inStr.Length == 26 || inStr.Length == 31)
        {
            int indexOfSpace = inStr.IndexOf(':');
            string Acc = inStr.Substring(indexOfSpace + 1);

            txtData7.Text = Acc;

            string test = inStr;

            if (test.Length == 25 || test.Length == 34 || test.Length == 33 || test.Length == 26)
            {
                label21.Text = "Check on patient!";
                label21.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else if (test.Length == 32)
            {
                label21.Text = "";
                label21.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
            }
        }

        else
        {

        }

         if (txtData1.Text != "" && txtData2.Text != "" && txtData3.Text != "" && txtData4.Text != "" && txtData5.Text != "" && txtData6.Text != "" && txtData7.Text != "")
        {
            try
            {
                connection2.Open();
                OleDbCommand command2 = new OleDbCommand();
                command2.Connection = connection2;
                command2.CommandText = "insert into MedicalRecord (PatientNumber,FirstName,LastName,IC,Temperature,ECG,Systolic,Diastolic,Pulse) values('" + txt_pnorec.Text + "','" + txt_fnamerec.Text + "','" + txt_lnamerec.Text + "','" + txt_icrec.Text + "','" + txtData2.Text + "','" + txtData3.Text + "','" + txtData4.Text + "','" + txtData5.Text + "','" + txtData6.Text + "')";

                command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Info Stored");
                connection2.Close();

                txtData1.Text = "";
                txtData2.Text = "";
                txtData3.Text = "";
                txtData4.Text = "";
                txtData5.Text = "";
                txtData6.Text = "";
                txtData7.Text = "";

                Thread.Sleep(interval);
                MessageBox.Show("Start");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex);
            }
            txtData1.Text = "";
            txtData2.Text = "";
            txtData3.Text = "";
            txtData4.Text = "";
            txtData5.Text = "";
            txtData6.Text = "";
            txtData7.Text = "";  
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Run your Thread.Sleep and associated actions on a different thread.

Comment: Are you delaying the UI thread? If you split up the thread and delay this one, the UI thread will remain responsive.

Comment: Do you have any relevant code you could show?

Comment: Hi Hjalmar, i have added the codes

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple ways to achieve this. One example is to use a task with a delay:

```
Task.Delay(10000).ContinueWith(x => 
{
    //Place the code you want delayed here.
});
```

Another example could be to use a [BackgroundWorker](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99143/BackgroundWorker-Class-Sample-for-Beginners) which is made for this exact purpose.

Answer (score 2):

```
Task.Delay(10000).ContinueWith(x => 
{
    //...
});
```

Have a look at [Task.Delay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194873(v=vs.110).aspx) and [ContinueWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321405(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Gusdor: Thanks, fair enough. I've added some description. Question didn't have code by the time I wrote the answer. Just wanted to show a direction.

Comment: @CharithJ I think you should also mention that async/await has only appeared in .Net framework version 4.5 and therefore it cant be used for other versions of .Net framework

Answer (score 2):

you can use **Async and Await**

here is a good tutorial in combination with an GUI:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCW_eJA2FeY

you need to declare your function as `async`

```
public async void Foo()
{
    ...
}
```

than you can use:

```
await Task.Delay(10000);
```

it will release you GUI for the whole `Delay` and you can use your GUI while the `Delay` is waiting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Windows.Forms.Timer` to execute something after delay... (with no  UI thread freezing). Split your code on two parts. 1. Before delay 2. After delay

```
public partial class form1 : Form
{
   // i used namespace to ensure that we use 'correct' Timer and we do not 
   // confuse it with System.Timers.Timer or System.Threading.Timer
   System.Windows.Forms.Timer tmrDelay;

   void SomeMethodWithDelay()
   {
       // code before delay here
       tmrDelay.Enabled = true;
       tmrDelay.Tick += Timer_Tick;
   }

   private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Thread.Sleep(5000);

       // your code here

       // disables timer to stop it
       tmrDelay.Enabled = false;
   }
}
```

Benefit from using Timer is that it is a native windows forms tool that was  specially designed to help with this kind of problems. 
However you can still use modern things like `Tasks`, for example : `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Thread.Sleep(5000); // your method logic here });`